# Properly handling pipe() and close() in nested fork()

Tags: c, unix

I am trying to achieve a simple pipe for a given command `ls -alt | tail`. What I do is the following:

1. Parent forks to create child waits for child and prints out result on screen.
2. Child forks to create grandchild waits for grandchild then executes lhs given output of grandchild.
3. Grandchild executes right hand side `ls -alt` redirect into pipe.

I am having trouble properly handling `stdin/stdout` with `pipe()`. Below is my attempt.

```
int execute_commands(char **prodv, char **conv) {
    pid_t pid_cons, pid_prod;
    int pd[2];
    int status;

    pipe(pd);

    pid_cons = fork();
    if (pid_cons == 0) {
        // Child (consumer) process
        pid_prod = fork();
        if (pid_prod == 0) {
            // Grandchild (producer) process
            close(1);
            dup(pd[1]);
            close(pd[1]);
            close(pd[0]);
            if (execvp(prodv[0], prodv) == -1) {
                perror("Could not run producer command.\n");
                _exit(1);
            }
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else if (pid_prod < 0) {
            // Error forking
            perror("Error forking grandchild.\n");
        } else {
            // Child process waiting for grandchild
            do {
                waitpid(pid_prod, &status, WUNTRACED);
            } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
        }
        close(0);
        dup(pd[0]);
        close(pd[0]);
        close(pd[1]);
        if (execvp(conv[0], conv) == -1) {
            perror("Could not run consumer command.\n");
            _exit(1);
        }
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if (pid_cons < 0) {
        // Error forking
        perror("Error forking child.\n");
    } else {
        // Parent process waiting for child
        dup(1);
        close(pd[0]);
        close(pd[1]);
        do {
            waitpid(pid_cons, &status, WUNTRACED);
        } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Ideally my output screen would be like this:

```
MyShell: ls -alt | tail

OUTPUT

MyShell: new command...  <---- BUT I NEVER REACH THIS & REMAIN STUCK AFTER OUTPUT EMPTY SCREEN
```

This tells me that I am not handling the `pipe()` correctly as I never return back to my terminal input function and am stuck somewhere after output.

Comment: What happens when you hard-code the commands instead of passing them in as arguments, and/or use two processes instead of three?

Comment: Haven't done that but I assume it would work because this does except that I seem to be mishandling close()